# overflow-x in flexbox enabled element not allowing scroll

Tags: css, flexbox, horizontal-scrolling

I know there are questions very similar to and possibly duplicates of this question, but applying those learnings still hasn't been able to get this 100% working. Some answers fix one part, some the other part, but I've not been able to figure out a full solution.

I have a layout that I arranged using flexbox settings. I want a main work area, a control panel on the right side, and a dock on the bottom that will horizontally scroll to show a dynamic number of items. I have [a mock up in a codepen](https://codepen.io/chris-schmitz/pen/NWjrbLJ?editors=1100):

[image: layout]

I have the major sections laid out here:

```
<div class="layout">
  
  <div class="workspace">
    <div class="animation-frame"></div>
    <div class="dock">
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

And styled here:

```
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100vh;width:100vw;}

.box  {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  min-width:100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin:5px;
}

.layout {
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  background:lightblue;
}

.workspace {
  background: lightgray;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.animation-frame {
  background: cyan;
  flex:1;
}

.dock {
  background: green;
  height:120px;
  display:flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.controls {
  background: orangered;
  width:120px;
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that when I try to set the "dock" with the property `overflow-x: scroll` the content still stretches the container:

[image]

I know if I force the width on the dock I can get the overflow to work:

[image: hard coded]

But then I lose the resizing flexibility that flexbox was giving me.

Is there a way to get both the dynamic horizontal size while still allowing for the horizontal scrolling?

Comment: If you're keeping your controls of `width: 120px` you can set the width of your dock to `width: calc(100vw - 120px);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your controls will have that 120 px width this might be what you're looking for

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100vh;width:100vw;}

.box  {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  min-width:100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin:5px;
}

.layout {
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  background:lightblue;
}

.workspace {
  background: lightgray;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.animation-frame {
  background: cyan;
  flex:1;
}

.dock {
  background: green;
  height:120px;
  display:flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /* This line was the only change*/
  width: calc(100vw - 120px);
}

.controls {
  background: orangered;
  width:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  
  <div class="workspace">
    <div class="animation-frame"></div>
    <div class="dock">
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
        <div class='box'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! I forgot about the calc function in css. yeah that fixed size isn't going to change. I updated my codepen to confirm it worked so now I can go apply it to the real thing. Thanks for the help!